# checking equality of a part of two files

Tags: linux, bash, diff

Is it possible to check if first line of two files is equal using `diff`(or another easy bash command)?

[Generally checking equality of first/last `k` lines, or even lines i to j]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To diff the first k lines of two files:

```
$ diff <(head -k file1) <(head -k file2)
```

Similary, to diff the last k lines:

```
$ diff <(tail -k file1) <(tail -k file2)
```

To diff lines i to j:

```
diff <(sed -n 'i,jp' file1) <(sed -n 'i,jp' file2)
```

Comment: What does `p` mean in 'i,jp'?

Comment: and to check equality: `if diff ...; then echo "equal"; else echo "not equal"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

My solution seems rather basic and beginner when compared to dogbane's above, but here it is all the same!

```
echo "Comparing the first line from file $1 and $2 to see if they are the same."

FILE1=`head -n 1 $1`
FILE2=`head -n 1 $2`

echo $FILE1 > tempfile1.txt
echo $FILE2 > tempfile2.txt

if diff "tempfile1.txt" "tempfile2.txt"; then
    echo Success
else
    echo Fail
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses the [filterdiff](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/filterdiff.1.php) program of the [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) program collection. The following command shows the difference between file1 and file2 from line number j to k:

```
diff -U 0 file1 file2 | filterdiff --lines j-k
```

Answer (score 0):

below command displays the first line of both the files.

```
krithika.450> head -1 temp1.txt temp4.txt
==> temp1.txt <==
Starting CXC <...> R5x BCMBIN (c)  AB 2012

==> temp4.txt <==
Starting CXC <...> R5x BCMBIN (c)  AB 2012
```

Below command displays yes if the first line in both the filesare equal.

```
krithika.451> head -1 temp4.txt temp1.txt | awk '{if(NR==2)p=$0;if(NR==5){q=$0;if(p==q)print "yes"}}'
yes
krithika.452>
```